# Get collection of recently updated products

Tags: magento-1, collection

I'm trying to create a collection of all products that have been updated in my store the past 24 hours.

The following code seems to be ok to me. Although I have tried numerous altering versions of it, the collection always ends up with 0 products.

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
$last_allowed_update = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($now.'- 24 hours') );

$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('updated_at', array('from'=>$last_allowed_update));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is better to use Magento framework to get the date

you should use

> Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate('Y-m-d H:i:s');

try this code

```
$now = Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$last_allowed_update = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($now.'- 24 hours') );

$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('updated_at', array('from'=>$last_allowed_update));
```

Comment: Thank for this suggestion. But I still get zero products.

Comment: Do you have updateed products in the last 24 hours? Just try to open any product and click save

Comment: Yes, of course there are updated products. Filtering products in magento administration by Date Updated, gives me about 300 products updated the pas 24 hours